Postgres Query to join multiple tables properly
I want to join two tables to get the output as shown in Table4. Below are the details:
Table1: SalesData



Date
PlatformId
UnitsSold
Revenue
ChannelId




2024-07-01
ABCD1
12
1200
1


2024-07-02
ABCD1
11
1000
1


2024-07-01
ABCD2
4
1200
2


2024-07-03
ABCD3
42
9000
3


2024-07-03
ABCD3
10
1000
2



Table2: AdsData



Date
PlatformCode
AdSpend




2024-07-01
1A
1000


2024-07-02
1A
1500


2024-07-01
2B
4000


2024-07-03
3C
4200



Table3: PlatformMapping



PlatformId
Platformcode




ABCD1
1A


ABCD2
2B


ABCD3
3C



Desired Output (Table4)



Date
PlatformId
UnitsSold
Revenue
ChannelId
AdSpend




2024-07-01
ABCD1
12
1200
1
1000


2024-07-02
ABCD1
11
1000
1
1500


2024-07-01
ABCD2
4
1200
2
4000


2024-07-03
ABCD3
32
9000
3
3200


2024-07-03
ABCD3
10
1000
2
1000



Here, the AdSpend is joined based on the PlatformId and Date with PlatformCode from Table3 and Table2.
I tried writing the following queries using CTEs but they didn't work as expected:
WITH AdSpendMapped AS (
    SELECT
        t1.date,
        t1.platformid,
        t1.UnitsSold,
        t2.AdSpend
    FROM SalesData t1
    JOIN PlatformMapping t3 ON t1.platformid = t3.PlatformId
    JOIN AdsData t2 ON t2.PlatformCode = t3.Platformcode AND t2.date = t1.date
),
TotalUnits AS (
    SELECT
        date,
        platformid,
        SUM(UnitsSold) AS TotalUnits
    FROM SalesData
    GROUP BY date, platformid
)
SELECT
    a.date,
    a.platformid,
    a.UnitsSold,
    a.ChannelId,
    COALESCE((a.AdSpend * a.totalquantitysold / NULLIF(t.TotalUnits, 0)), 0) AS AdSpend
FROM AdSpendMapped a
JOIN TotalUnits t
    ON a.date = t.date AND a.platformid = t.platformid;


Never say  it "didn't work as expected". Tell us in what way it did not work. Does the query return too many rows or too few or unexpected values or do you get an error message? If you get an error message, tell us so and show us the message.

Your query cannot work, because you access AdSpendMapped.ChannelId in your main query, but your AdSpendMapped CTE doesn't have a ChannelId in its select list.
You want to show all salesdata rows. Along with them you want their adsdata.adspend divided by the ratio of unitssold within a group of platformid and date.
For the ratio calculation you can use the window function SUM OVER. In PostgreSQL the division operator / gives you an integer result when working with integers (like we did in primary school). So, we must change our integer column to a decimal first in order to get proper results.
SELECT
  sd.date,
  sd.platformid,
  sd.unitssold,
  sd.revenue,
  sd.channelid,
  ad.adspend * (sd.unitssold::decimal / sum(sd.unitssold) over (partition by sd.date, sd.platformid)) as adspent
FROM salesdata sd
JOIN platformmapping pm ON pm.platformid = sd.platformid
JOIN adsdata ad ON ad.platformcode = pm.platformcode AND ad.date = sd.date


If you see the last two rows closely in the desired output table. You can see that I want to divide the adspend if the channelid is different but platformid is same. In that case I want to divide the ad spend in the ratio of the UnitsSold @Thorsten Kettner

I have also updated the query in the question.

Okay. That escaped me. This is the main problem with your request. You are not telling us what the query is supposed to do. The explanation you have given here, should be in your request. The other problem wirth your request: you still haven't told us what the issue with your own query is. It should be a syntax error, as already mentioned, so why don't you tell us, but have us guess instead? Please edit the request again in order to give that information. As to the ratio: the simplest way to get this is with a window function. I've updated my answer accordingly.

One option is to Sum(unitssold) Over()  twice - once partitioned by platformid and once partitioned by platformid and channelid combined and calculate the ratio out of those two summs.
WITH    -- S a m p l e     D a t a :
  salesdata ( date, platformid, unitssold, revenue, channelid ) AS
    ( Select '2024-07-01', 'ABCD1', 12, 1200, 1 Union All
      Select '2024-07-02', 'ABCD1', 11, 1000, 1 Union All
      Select '2024-07-01', 'ABCD2', 4,  1200, 2 Union All
      Select '2024-07-03', 'ABCD3', 32, 9000, 3 Union All
      Select '2024-07-03', 'ABCD3', 10, 1000, 2
    ), 
  adsdata ( date, platformcode, adspend ) AS 
    ( Select '2024-07-01',  '1A',   1000 Union All
      Select '2024-07-02',  '1A',   1500 Union All
      Select '2024-07-01',  '2B',   4000 Union All
      Select '2024-07-03',  '3C',   4200
    ), 
  platformmapping ( platformid, platformcode ) AS
    ( Select 'ABCD1', '1A' Union All 
      Select 'ABCD2', '2B' Union All
      Select 'ABCD3', '3C'
    ) 

--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select     sd.date, sd.platformid, sd.unitssold, sd.revenue, sd.channelid,
           --
           Round( ad.adspend * 
                  ( Sum(sd.unitssold::Decimal) 
                        Over( Partition By sd.platformid, sd.channelid ) 
                    / 
                    Sum(sd.unitssold) Over( Partition By sd.platformid ) 
                  ) 
                , 0 ) as adspend
From        platformmapping pm
Inner Join  salesdata sd ON( sd.platformid = pm.platformid )
Inner Join  adsdata ad ON( ad.platformcode = pm.platformcode )
Where       sd.date = ad.date
Order By    sd.platformid, sd.date, sd.unitssold Desc

/*    R e s u l t : 
date        platformid  unitssold      revenue  channelid   adspend
----------  ----------  ---------  -----------  ---------  --------
2024-07-01  ABCD1              12         1200          1      1000
2024-07-02  ABCD1              11         1000          1      1500
2024-07-01  ABCD2               4         1200          2      4000
2024-07-03  ABCD3              32         9000          3      3200
2024-07-03  ABCD3              10         1000          2      1000    */

See the fiddle here.
